# How does folding paper affect the geometry angles?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, origami

This is how you create equilateral triangles.
[image: Equilateral triangles]

But I have noticed that if you start of with a flawed fold, you can still end up with equilateral triangles, how come?

[image: ![Flawed]

Instructions:

Need: Rectangular strip paper.

Step one make an arbitrary crease.
Take the right side of the paper and align in to the crease, now fold, you should have another crease.
Now alternate, fold up vertically then fold down.

Code: Down, down, up, down, up, down...
[image: First step]
[image: Second step]
[image: Third step]

Why does any arbitrary crease lead to equilateral triangles.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> There's information missing in the question, without which answering (or even understanding what you're asking) is difficult. Can you please say more about (i) the starting shape of the paper, (ii) what rules dictate successive folds, (iii) in what sense you observe equilateral triangles emerging or normalizing from successive folds, (iv) what you mean by "approach" (configurations of creases approaching equilateral triangles? or is there some other goal of folding, and the equilateral triangles are an unexpected effect)? [...]

Comment: If those points are not easy to add, even something as simple as a detailed, reproducible example, e.g., "I start with a thin strip of paper and fold it [in this specific way] and observe that [something happens related to equilateral triangles]. Can someone explain why this happens?"

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I have completely changed my post and added pictures. Hopefully now it is clear.

Comment: It's not hard to see, if you know a little Calculus, that the sequence of angles converges rather quickly to 60° independently of the angle you start from.

Comment: I have taken calculus, unfortunately I am one of those who just followed instructions. Now I am trying to change that. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: First, write down an equation for the angle going in and the angle going out using geometry. I suspect it’ll be something like $f(x)=(360-x)/2$. Then show that this sequence converges to an equilateral by considering what happens to the distance from the limit after each iteration ($x-120$).

Comment: I don't get the instructions (maybe I'm a little dense) how are you getting the nearly horizontal fold, after the first flawed fold?

Comment: @CalvinKhor No, you are not dense, my explanation is bad. Look at the new picture OR follow the instructions and try it!. Hopefully it is clear. Thank you for showing interest!

Comment: @Eric Not sure what you mean by angle going out? Since it's always three angles at every turn. Please check the updated picture. As for distance from the limit, do you mean (from the first picture) f(1)=18 degrees? That every point away from the first fold is x. Anther example f(2)=46. I am positive this is not what you mean but it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: At one time I thought I understood your procedure, but then you labeled your examples to show that where two creases met at the edge of the paper they form three different angles. I expected two angles the same, so obviously I misunderstood something. Perhaps showing one step at a time for the strip that started with an $18$ degree angle. How does that result in $78$ degrees and $84$ degrees?

Comment: I meant just choose one of those angles (say the left most one) and calculate the next one as a function of that. If I understand it right, the other two angles should be $90-x/2$, so if that’s $60$, then you’re set.

Comment: @DavidK Updated images, hopefully it is clear now. Thank you for showing interest!

Comment: @Eric Wow! First and foremost thank you! I don't know why my first thought wasn't recursive formula. Now, what take home message should one take away from this? What about folding causes this to happen? How come this, correct formula, was your first instinct? I just don't know what to make of this information is what I am saying. Also, where can I read more about this type of thing?

Comment: Thank you, now that all the images are oriented the same way, I managed to follow the instructions :) interesting question

Comment: Notice that in the second frame of the sequence, when we can see the $18$ degree angle but the rest of the strip is folded over itself, the angles at the bottom corners of the two folded-over parts must be equal (since they are literally lying one on top of the other). So they must both be $81^\circ$ (as explained in Calvin Khor's answer). If you were measuring the creases with a protractor then a three-degree error is not too surprising, but if we want to understand the ideal process (without physical error) then the formula takes precedence over the protractor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem setup

Consider the strip laid horizontally as in the question, with the first crease made:

```
   ,---\-------------------------------
   |   \ 2 = 180º-                 ...
   '-----\-----------------------------
```

Let $\theta=\theta_1$ be the angle on the left of the first crease as measured along the bottom edge. (In the above diagram, $\theta<90º.$) Let $$\theta_n=\text{left angle of the $n$th crease along the } \begin{cases}\text{bottom edge} &\text{if } n \text{ odd}\\ \text{top edge} &\text{if } n \text{ even}\end{cases}$$
Making the second crease creates a line that bisects the angle $2\alpha=180º-\theta$. A little bit of geometry about alternate angles [(see proposition 29)](https://www.pitt.edu/%7Ejdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/non_Euclid_Euclid/Elements.html) shows that $\alpha$ is in fact $\theta_2$. In general
$$ \theta_n = 90º-\frac{\theta_{n-1}}2$$

### Limit computation

You could quote a theorem about contractive sequences to see that $\theta_n$ has a limit, which must then be $60º$. Alternatively, observe that we can rewrite the above as
$$ \theta_n-60º = \frac{-1}{2}( \theta_{n-1} - 60º)$$
so $T_n:=\theta_n-60º$ is a geometric sequence with common ratio $-1/2$ whose modulus is less than $1$. We deduce $T_n\to 0$ and hence $\theta_n\to 60º$, and moreover we obtain the explicit formula
$$ \theta_n =60+ T_n = 60º + \left(\frac{-1}2\right)^{n-1}(\theta_1-60º).$$

### Verification of example

In particular if $\theta_1 = 18º$ then the theoretically correct angles are
\begin{align}
\theta_1 &= 18º\\
\theta_2 &= 81º \\ 
\theta_3 &= 49.5º \\
\theta_4 &= 65.25º \\
\theta_5 &= 57.375º \\
\theta_6 &= 61.3125º \\
\theta_7 &= 59.34375º \\
\theta_8 &= 60.328125º
\end{align}
which is quite close to your  example.

Comment: Completely blown away and grateful for this answer! 
The way you changed the formula to Tn and showed it approach 0 was exceptional.
I will happily accept this answer!